# parseFloat ignores characters after decimal point

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want my function to format a string or number into a decimal number with X digits after decimal point. My problem is that when I am passing `3.0004` to my function I get `3`. I have read the documentation and it seems that whenever `parseFloat` finds a `.` for example

> it returns the value up to that character, ignoring the invalid
> character and characters following it.

I understand it does that but how do I return `3.00` then? I want my function to always return a number with digits after decimal point. The reason I am using `parseFloat` is because I want it to return either a number or null.

Here's my implementation

```
const toDecimal = (number: number | string, digits: number = 2): number | null => {
  switch (typeof number) {
    case 'number':
      return parseFloat(number.toFixed(digits));
    case 'string':
      const parsedDecimal = parseFloat(number);
      return isNaN(parsedDecimal)
        ? null
        : parseFloat(parsedDecimal.toFixed(digits));
    default:
      return null;
  }
}


toDecimal(3.0004)  // will return 3
```

Comment: The numeric value is implicately `3` and `3.0` and `3.00` and so on. The trailing zeroes are implied and continue infinitely. Whether they're displayed or not is entirely up to the number to string conversion. They will only appear while the value is presented as a string and only if the conversion added them.

Answer (score 1):

1. @Ouroborus comment on your question is key to understand what's going on: "The numeric value is implicately 3 and 3.0 and 3.00 and so on. The trailing zeroes are implied and continue infinitely"
2. When you pass `"3.004"` as the only parameter, then `digits` is `2` by default, and the number is then fixed to `"3.00"` because of `toFixed`.

If you want `"3.004"` to be properly converted to `3.004`, just call your function with a higher precision:

```
toDecimal("3.004", 3)
```

Comment: I did notice passing 3 digits works however I wrote this function to display prices on a page so 3 digits after decimal point doesn't quite fit in. Do you reckon I should be returning a string without the final `parseFloat`?

Comment: The data type you return depends on you (or your requirements). If you need to display money, then you must stablish a rounding policy. For example, if the final value is `"3.004"` you must make a decision whether to round up to `3.01` or down to `3.00`

Comment: I do agree however, is returning a string rather than a number a good decision?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function:

```
const toDecimalFixed = (number: number | string, digits: number = 2) => {
  const parsed = toDecimal(number, digits)
  return parsed == null ? null : parsed.toFixed(2)
}

console.log(toDecimalFixed(3.0004))  // will return "3.00"
```

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string, not a number. I could just skip the final `parseFloat` to achieve the same result.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk in that case this answer is the right one https://stackoverflow.com/a/68468361/16493446